# transfer file between one server to another server by using ftp_put()

Tags: php, linux, ftp

I want to transfer file between one server to another server by using ftp_put() function in php

I send ftp information as ftp server ip & ftp username & ftp password by get method to my server
my server receive information and use ftp_put() for upload file to another server

I just one problem all source path working but when I use /root/"VirtualBox VMs"/file name path I can not upload file in FTP

My code using for this method is:

[image]

thank you

Comment: /root/ is the home directory of root, which can only be accessed by root.

Comment: What error do you receive?